# RShiny: Using radiobuttons to anonymize certain columns in the dataframe

Tags: r, shiny

I have built a RShiny Web Application which allows user to modify parameters and it updates the table dynamically. **Upon clicking the Radiobutton, it should automatically update and anonymize certain columns like Member Names and IDs**. However, due to the radio buttons the Data frame is not visible. Due to security reasons, I can't upload the entire code but I have mentioned the code which pertains to the problem. The app looks like this

[image]

```
    ## Deidentify Personal Information
    PCP_Incentives_df_Reac4 <- reactive({
      #req(input$DeIdentificationcheckbox)
      df3 = PCP_Incentives_df_Reac3()
      df3$MemberNumber_DId = sapply(df3$MemberNumber, digest, algo = "crc32")
      df3$MemberName_DId = sapply(df3$MemberName, digest, algo = "crc32")
      df3$SubscriberFirstName_DId = sapply(df3$SubscriberFirstName, digest, algo = "crc32")
      df3$SubscriberLastName_DId = sapply(df3$SubscriberLastName, digest, algo = "crc32")
      df3 = df3[!is.na(df3$MemberPCPNPI),c("MemberNumber_DId","MemberFirstName","MemberLastName","MemberName_DId","MemberGender",
                                           "MemberDOB","MemberAge","Relationship","ProjectedRisk","MemberPCPName","MemberPCPNPI","MemberAddress","MemberCity",
                                           "MemberState","MemberZip","EmployerName","SubscriberDOB","SubscriberPolicyNo","SubscriberFirstName_DId",
                                           "SubscriberLastName_DId","OfficialGroupNbr","ReferralPer1000","TotalPMPM","Incentive_ReferralPMPM",
                                           "Incentive_QualityPMPM","Incentive_AccessPMPM","Incentive_UtilizationPMPM","TotalIncentive_Available",
                                           "TotalIncentives_Earned")]
      ## Radio Button - input$DeIdentificationButton
      if (input$DeIdentificationButton==1){
        return(df3)
      }
      else {
        return(PCP_Incentives_df_Reac3()[!is.na(PCP_Incentives_df_Reac3()$MemberPCPNPI),
                                         c("MemberNumber","MemberFirstName","MemberLastName","MemberName","MemberGender",
                                           "MemberDOB","MemberAge","Relationship","ProjectedRisk","MemberPCPName","MemberPCPNPI","MemberAddress","MemberCity",
                                           "MemberState","MemberZip","EmployerName","SubscriberDOB","SubscriberPolicyNo","SubscriberFirstName",
                                           "SubscriberLastName","OfficialGroupNbr","ReferralPer1000","TotalPMPM","Incentive_ReferralPMPM",
                                           "Incentive_QualityPMPM","Incentive_AccessPMPM","Incentive_UtilizationPMPM","TotalIncentive_Available",
                                           "TotalIncentives_Earned")])
      }
      
    })
    
    
    ## Displaying Table
    output$contents <- DT::renderDataTable(server = F,{
                                                                  
      PCP_Incentives_df_Reac4()
    },extensions = c("Buttons"),
    options = list(dom = 'Blfrtip',buttons = c("copy", "csv","excel"),
    filter = list(position = 'top'),
                   lengthMenu=list(c(50,100,150,3000,5000),c('50','100','150','3000','5000')),
                   pageLength=150,
                   initComplete = JS(
                       "function(settings, json) {",
                       "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': '#2fa4e7', 'color': 'white'});",
                       "}"),
                   columnDefs=list(list(targets = c(22:28), render = formatThousands)),
                   searching = T),  
    style = 'bootstrap',
    class = 'cell-border stripe',
    rownames = FALSE
    )
```

The table is perfectly visible if I remove the deidentification step. Please tell me where I am going wrong.
Thanks

Comment: You have a better chance of getting help if you post a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Your code is not reproducible

Comment: Hello Thanks for the help. It looks like there was a problem with the DataTable library. I just updated the package and it worked.